# Redirectly all request to a folder to the same folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want redirect all the url request to folder "main" to the same folder ( in fact to index.php inside folder "main")

For example I want requests such as main/7512753876873 or main/654747476 are all redirected to the main/index.php

I tested most Rewrite rules and conditions but none of them worked. 
How I should do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ... here is a link to an article on what is considered good content for a question ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: "None of them worked" does not really help. You need to be much more specific. The examples you can find here or in the documentation certainly _do_ work. If you claim they don't work for you then most likely the issue is not those answers but your very specific situation or the way you tried to apply them. Both things you did not tell us anything about. So what kind of answer do you expect, beside the repetition of already existing answers?